# Reversing entropy by statistics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If the second law of thermodynamics is about statistics, there's a chance of a specific microstate of a very unlikely macrostate happen, so the entropy would be reversed. So, the Universe could return to it's initial macrostate spontaneously? I know it's very very very unlikely but still possible probabilistically, right? Considering an infinite amount of time, the Universe would "restart" itself infinite times.

Comment: There is a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) in classical mechanics which says so, but the timescale of the event is way larger than the age of the universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If the universe is bounded and finite, then via the Poincaré recurrence theorem[1], the Fluctuation theorem[2], and some assumptions (e.g. all previous states accessible), the universe will get arbitrarily close to any previous state an infinite amount of times. Over time parts will spontaneously fluctuate to a lower entropy state, and over arbitrary time, enough parts can and will fluctuate to achieve what you ask.

> [1]"**Poincaré recurrence theorem states that certain systems will,
> after a sufficiently long but finite time, return to a state
> arbitrarily close to...their initial state**. The result applies to
> isolated mechanical systems subject to some constraints, e.g., **all
> particles must be bound to a finite volume**"
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem
>
> [2]"While the second law of thermodynamics predicts that the entropy
> of an isolated system should tend to increase until it reaches
> equilibrium, it became apparent after the discovery of statistical
> mechanics that **the second law is only a statistical one, suggesting
> that there should always be some nonzero probability that the entropy
> of an isolated system might spontaneously decrease; the fluctuation
> theorem precisely quantifies this probability.**"
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation_theorem

But the universe is unbounded and infinite as far as we can tell. So if the universe is to end up in a previous state, it can't be through Poincaré recurrence. However there could still be a universe-wide fluctuation for all the particles, it just isn't a guaranteed process like the Poincaré recurrence theorem promises. That's just for the particles though, not spacetime itself. If they all get reassembled to due a massive fluctuation, spacetime itself is still accelerating apart. So the universe can't revert to a previous state unless something changes the cosmological constant and/or dark energy as well. And we need to know more about them to say if that's possible.